# How is this letter or symbol pronounced mathematically?

Tags: notation

1)How is this letter or symbol pronounced mathematically?

$$\overline k$$

2) $'$  is this sign just a symbol of derivative? For example:

$$k'$$ Do we only understand this as a derivative?

Comment: "$k$ bar", or "bar $k$" for the first. For the second, the answer is "no", because the "prime" symbol sometimes is just a way to mark a variable making it into a new variable, similar to the way numerical subscripts are used. So $k$, $k'$, $k''$, $k_1$, $k_2$ are sometimes all regarded as just different variables.

Comment: "k bar" and "k dash". They can mean whatever you want them to mean and whatever you tell the reader they mean.

Comment: $\bar{k}$ can be pronounced as $k$ bar. In statistics $\bar{k}$ means arithmetic mean. If $k \in \mathbb{C}$, hence $k$ is complex, then $\bar{k}$ sometimes is used for the complex conjugate of $k$. There might also be other usages just to reuse $k$ but to prevent confusion you could write $\bar{k}$. This is most often used when there is some relationship between $k$ and $\bar{k}$. But I have never seen it for denoting derivatives.

Comment: Usually context will yield whether or not the prime refers to Newton's prime derivative notation or just simply to new variable. For instance, in an ODE class you'll see e.g. $y''+cy=0$. But in another class you might see e.g. "let $n,n' \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $n\neq n'$... ."

Comment: 1) k bar 2) sometimes primes are used for other things, for example $k'$ could just be a variable name.

Comment: I am very grateful for this wonderful information. to all of you.

Comment: @kimchilover I disagree. I did not receive my early mathematical training in Britain or America. I mean $k'$ when I say '$k$ prime'. The place where I receive my early mathematical training has stronger historical connection with Britain than wih America.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what mathematical area you were studying when you saw it probably. Just like x isn't always referring to the $x$-axis or $y$ to the $y$- axis on the real plane it could be any Cartesian product etc. $\circ$ could be used as function composition or other compositions as well as in place of the degree symbol if talking about temperature. The verniculum (bar) in fractions and roots means take everything under it together as one thing.  in repeating decimals it is a short way to show what part repeats.  the tick could mean first derivative, it could also mean the preimage of function k in a function context for example.  math symbols get reused a lot. $\aleph$ could be a variable or with a subscript could be referring to a type of infinity for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. “Kay bar” (or maybe “bar kay” if $k$ is replaced with something long)
2. “Kay prime” could hypothetically be used to notate anything, depending on the author and field. However, $k’$ would generally be accepted as any of the following:

   - the derivative of a function $k$
   - the complement of an event $k$ (in which case it would probably be pronounced “kay complement”)
   - a symbol that has been distinguished from an otherwise defined but related $k$ (e.g., spacetime dilation, integration dummy variables)